# Where to place reporting functionality in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My rails app needs to have a semi-extensive ability for an admin to generate reports. It is an online ticket-selling system for concerts and the reports range from viewing a list of all the users to viewing specific accounting details for certain shows/venues/etc.

Is there a specific location in the app this code should be placed? Should I have, for instance, the report that shows all users just call the Users#index method with certain parameters. That works fine for an easy report, but what about more complex accounting reports? Should they have their own controller?

Answer (score 1):

It's not just reporting functionality you should be looking at - it's any functionality which should be segregated by role.

My approach is to namespace my controllers by role, so my `routes.rb` would look something like the following:

```
# admin will access /admin/reports/users, etc. 
namespace admin
  resource :reports do
    get :users, on: :collection
    resource :shows do
      get :accounts, on: :member
    end
    resource :venues
  end
end

# normal users will access /shows, etc
resource :shows
resource :venues
```

With this approach, normal users will be routed to `ShowsController` and `VenuesController`, while admin users are routed to `Admin::ShowsController` and `Admin::VenuesController`. Use partials to DRY up views which should be seen by both roles.

With this approach, you won't need conditionals to check whether your controller / view is being accessed by an admin or a normal user.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to abstract away some of the logic into modules, and store them in `app/lib/modules`. Those modules can call upon models/controllers in the app, and manipulate the data in any way you wish. Structuring your app this way keeps concerns like reporting outside of the main app logic (which is selling tickets). I've done this with modules, and you can and when you need to call that module, you can do so with this syntax: `ModuleName::ClassName::class_method`